# Trying to write query connected to sort browser

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm a beginner to Progress and to programming, would be really greatful for some help.

Trying to write a query connected to a browser. In my window there is also a radioset (that sorts the browser, for example by name or age)
and a fillin (if anything is written there and "ok" is pushed then only the posts
where the surname begins with whatever is written are to be displayed in the browser.

The radioset has a default-value, on value-chagned the browser is opened again.

I've tried to write my query like the following and the sorting by the radioset works, but not the fillin (Showeing the error message that it doesn't understand the query):

```
DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER pfiSurname AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cQuery AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE hQueryHandle AS HANDLE    NO-UNDO.
&SCOPED-DEFINE BROWSER brMembers

DO WITH FRAME  {&FRAME-NAME}:
    ASSIGN rsSort.

  IF fiSurname = '' THEN 
    ASSIGN cQuery = 'FOR EACH Member NO-LOCK by member.' + rsSort.
  ELSE 
    ASSIGN cQuery = 'FOR EACH member NO-LOCK WHERE member.surname BEGINS' 
     + fiSurname + 'BY member.' + rsSort. 

  hQueryHandle = {&BROWSER}:QUERY.
  hQueryHandle:QUERY-PREPARE(cQuery).
  hQueryHandle:QUERY-OPEN().

END.
END PROCEDURE.
```

Comment: It might help to show the actual text of the error message.  My best guess is that rsSort has no value and that, therefore, cQuery is leading to an invalid QUERY-PREPARE().  Possibly because "ASSIGN rsSort." should be "ASSIGN INPUT rsSort." if this code is the body of a user-interface trigger.  But it is hard to tell since this is just a small fragment of the real code and the actual error is unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to space before and after your string bits, enclose the surname in quotes, and use screen-value to the rsSort bit. Just to help you understand for the first part, message the query string. You'll see something like this:
For each member no-lock where member.surname beginsEllenby member.chosenfield

When it should be 
For each member no-lock where member.surname begins "Ellen" by member.chosenfield

And just to make sure, I'd message the value of rsSort
So I recommend you change to

```
 ASSIGN cQuery = 'FOR EACH member NO-LOCK WHERE member.surname BEGINS ' 
 + Quoter(fiSurname) + ' BY member.' + rsSort:screen-value.
```

And like I said, message the entire thing, copy it and try to write it directly in the Progress window, I find it helps me a lot to debug these dynamic queries this way.

Comment: That was it, the quoter and spaces. Good tip to show the query in a message! Thank you!

Comment: If the answer has solved your problem you should mark it as "correct".

Answer (score 1):

Add QUOTER() around fiSurname and extra SPACE's after the BEGINS and before the BY within the quotes